# Method to detect if subsequent navigation will succeed

Tags: javascript, hta

I've got a legacy application that is launched from an `HTA`. I'm starting with a `file://` then immediately redirects the user to a web url `location.href="http://server/path"`.

**Is there a way to detect if navigation succeeded or not (or a way to detect if it *will* succeed)**

Ideas:

- `XHR` to the url to get HTTP response code before navigating to url. (Permission issue as the sites are not identical: file:// -> http://)
- `SCRIPT` element to a known path at url.
- Access url in `FRAME`. Then reload parent once it succeeds from either the result page or from the `HTA`.

Notes:

The URL will be a dynamic page (servlet) which are hosted on the app servers. The static content (images, etc) are hosted differently. By verifying the image, it doesn't guarantee that the real url works. Please have answers reflect this difference. (Thanks!)

Comment: XHR to the url would get the content and a 200 ok. Perhaps you want to do a HEAD instead of a GET/POST

Comment: @mplungjan The XHR isn't within the same protocol & server, so there's a permission exception. :(

Comment: An HTA should allow access across domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CALLING` page cannot directly know if its navigation will succeed or fail. Different methods can be used to increase the likelihood that it will occur, but ultimately it may or may not succeed.

Comment: Why not load the URL in an iframe?

Comment: @gilly3, That would change some assumptions of the application as it will resize itself.

Answer (score 0):

Load an image from the server and listen to the `onload` and `onerror` events.  The image can be just a one pixel transparent gif.

```
<img src="http://server/transparent.gif" onload="setServerAvailable(true);" onerror="setServerAvailable(false);" />
```

**Edit:** You can load the page in an iframe.  You can monitor the page health through JavaScript. You don't need to worry about the Same Origin Policy when working with an HTA.  Save this code as an HTA, then load the HTA and click the button.  You'll see that you are able to modify the frame content, even though it is in another domain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Test Same Origin Policy in HTA</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function modifyFrame()
            {
                var fr = document.body.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                fr.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 
                    "Cross domain scripting works in HTA";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940913/"></iframe>
        <br /><br />
        <button onclick="modifyFrame()">Modify cross-domain frame content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will ensure access to the server, but not solve the primary issue of an actual successful navigation of a webpage.

Comment: @gilly3 I'm concerned about the url I will be navigating to will succeed. Once I redirect and it fails, the app has lost control of the window and the user is screwed.

Comment: Then just host the page in an iframe.  Same Domain Policy does not apply to HTAs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the target web page, place a ping (`onload`) on the web page to the caller server registering the successful load.

Depending on your choice of technology the ping from the web page could be a simple call to a web service on the server registering the successful load in a central repository (ie. database). Your HTA could regularly check the database for loading status and act accordingly.

In summary what you need is:

1. A web service registering 'load status' for a page request. Save the
   loading status in a central database
2. On the loading web page call this web service after the page has fully loaded. On error set the status likewise.
3. In your HTA create a timer that checks (and displays) loading status. And acts according to the final status.

Comment: I've elaborated my suggested answer. Hope you get my idea? I know this solution is a bit complex, but since your HTA and web page are in different security scopes you need to communicate through a repository. At least that's how I see it... ;)

Comment: Once I set the location.href, I don't have a way to prevent the navigation (ignoring the user dialog with onbeforeunload). So how would this method help? How would this "ping-back" page be loaded? (XHR, script tag wouldn't work)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what I'm trying to say is that only the CALLED web page are able to register its load status. You can't do this from the CALLING HTA directly. If you don't have access to adjust the CALLED web page you're in trouble as I see it...

Comment: Exactly. If for some reason the server is down (maintenance maybe), I wouldn't want the customer to see some generic error page. Different layers could produce an error, the load balancer, firewall, app server... Just trying to add some polish for the user.